# Upload file in Cypress without input[type="file"] showing in DOM

Tags: angular, input, upload, cypress, antd

I am doing e2e testing on an Angular project with Ant design (NG-ZORRO). I have a button nz-button which on click opens the file explorer just like an  would do. On my modal component code, I have a `<input #file type="file" (change)="import($event.target)" />`. **It does not appear at all either in the DOM, in the UI or in Devtool**. It is triggered by an IMPORT button (which appears) in the footer that has a (click)="file.click()" property.

I want to use the .selectFile() method from Cypress in order to import a file through that IMPORT button, but the command : `cy.get(.import-button).selectFile('file.csv')` won't work because my button is not an `<input type="file">` ; and if I try to use `cy.get(input[type=file])` instead, Cypress does not find it, as **it does not appear on Devtool**.

Do you have an idea of why and/or may I test file uploading with Cypress in that case ?

I searched for an answer for many hours and still could not figure it out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to add the `{action:'drag-drop'}` option to the selectFile command.

> Setting the action to drag-drop changes the behavior of the command to instead mimic a user dragging files from the operating system into the browser, and dropping them over the selected subject. In this mode, ***the subject can be any DOM element*** or the document as a whole.

```js
cy.get(.import-button).selectFile('file.csv', {action:'drag-drop'})
```

From your description, I would say that the `<input>` used to fire the action is added on the fly by the application, which means it's going to be very hard to use it directly in the test.